# Magento 2: Adding full text search to custom grid results in error on count query

Tags: grid, magento2.3.5-p1, fulltext

I am trying to add full text search to a custom grid.
I have done the following steps

- added full text indexes to related columns in the table
- in the ui component xml file, added `<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>` node (tried with and without description)

The search bar appears on the grid page, but when I search for something I get the following error in exception log

```
[2020-07-24 10:05:59] report.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulltext' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `aw_helpdesk_ticket` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `aw_helpdesk_ticket_grid_flat` AS `flat` ON main_table.id = flat.ticket_id
 INNER JOIN `aw_helpdesk_department` AS `department` ON main_table.department_id = department.id WHERE (((`department_id` = '1'))) AND (((`fulltext` = 'test'))) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulltext' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `aw_helpdesk_ticket` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `aw_helpdesk_ticket_grid_flat` AS `flat` ON main_table.id = flat.ticket_id
 INNER JOIN `aw_helpdesk_department` AS `department` ON main_table.department_id = department.id WHERE (((`department_id` = '1'))) AND (((`fulltext` = 'test'))) at /Users/fkhan/Sites/TPM2/app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulltext' in 'where clause' at /Users/fkhan/Sites/TPM2/app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure in your ui component file dataProvider element is exist and is proper as

```
<dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="answer_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>answer_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>answer_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
```